# Summing up array values using multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the sum of all "amount" elements within my array based on customer and date range. Im wanting the output array (final result) to look something like this ...

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Yeung's Architects
        [customer_id] => 3
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-04-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 1543.64
        [account_id] => 75
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Clement's Cleaners
        [customer_id] => 8
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-04-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 2177.27
        [account_id] => 75
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Clement's Cleaners
        [customer_id] => 8
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-05-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 295.45
        [account_id] => 75
    )
 )
```

This is the sql call that I am using ...

```
SELECT c.company_name
     , i.customer_id
     , a.name
     , i.due_date
     , li.amount
     , li.account_id 
  FROM invoices i 
  JOIN customers c 
    ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id
  JOIN invoices_line_items li 
    ON li.guid = i.guid 
   AND li.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
  JOIN accounts a 
    ON a.guid = li.guid 
   AND a.account_id = li.account_id
 WHERE i.guid = ? 
   AND i.date >= "'.$firstOfThisMonth.'" ',array($guid));
```

The resulting array from the sql call to start working with...

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Yeung's Architects
        [customer_id] => 3
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-04-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 1362.73
        [account_id] => 75
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Yeung's Architects
        [customer_id] => 3
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-04-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 180.91
        [account_id] => 75
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Clement's Cleaners
        [customer_id] => 8
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-04-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 177.27
        [account_id] => 75
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Clement's Cleaners
        [customer_id] => 8
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-05-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 159.09
        [account_id] => 75
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Clement's Cleaners
        [customer_id] => 8
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-05-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 136.36
        [account_id] => 75
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Clement's Cleaners
        [customer_id] => 8
        [name] => Services
        [due_date] => 2019-04-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 2000.00
        [account_id] => 1
    )

   )
```

The code I am currently using to try and sum all of the amounts based on customer ID and the month of the invoice.

```
            $output = array($data[0]); $c = 1;
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if ($key > 0) {

                    if (in_array($value->customer_id,array_column($output, 'customer_id'))) {

                        $valueDate = substr($value->due_date,0,7);
                        foreach ($output as $k => $v) {
                            if ($v->customer_id == $value->customer_id) {
                                $vDate = substr($v->due_date,0,7);
                                if ($vDate == $valueDate) {
                                    $output[$k]->amount = $output[$k]->amount + $value->amount;
                                } else {
                                    $output[$c] = $value;
                                    $c++;
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        $output[$c] = $value;
                        $c++;
                    }

                }
            }

            return $output;
```

This is my final results from the above mentioned code...

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Yeung's Architects
        [customer_id] => 3
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-04-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 1543.64
        [account_id] => 75
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Clement's Cleaners
        [customer_id] => 8
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-04-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 2177.27
        [account_id] => 75
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Clement's Cleaners
        [customer_id] => 8
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-05-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 295.45
        [account_id] => 75
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Clement's Cleaners
        [customer_id] => 8
        [name] => Billable Expenses Income
        [due_date] => 2019-05-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 136.36
        [account_id] => 75
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Clement's Cleaners
        [customer_id] => 8
        [name] => Services
        [due_date] => 2019-04-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 2000.00
        [account_id] => 1
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [company_name] => Clement's Cleaners
        [customer_id] => 8
        [name] => Services
        [due_date] => 2019-04-19 00:00:00
        [amount] => 2000.00
        [account_id] => 1
    )

   )
```

The first 3 keys are the correct results but then there are 3 extra keys added which Im not sure how they are being added. My brain is now broken, please may someone help me out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not wanting to use SQL [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html)? Databases are great at this.

Comment: I thought about doing something like that but tbh my SQL is very basic.

Comment: MySQL is super powerful.. oh, wait ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I am following you just want to group this by `company_name` or is there another dimension? Doing this in SQL is actually very straightforward.

Query using an aggregate function, sum, and grouping by the company field. You can see below very little changed.

```
SELECT c.company_name
     , i.customer_id
     , a.name
     , i.due_date
     , SUM(li.amount)
     , AVG(li.amount)
     , li.account_id 
  FROM invoices i 
  JOIN customers c 
    ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id
  JOIN invoices_line_items li 
    ON li.guid = i.guid 
   AND li.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
  JOIN accounts a 
    ON a.guid = li.guid 
   AND a.account_id = li.account_id
 WHERE i.guid = ? 
   AND i.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
 GROUP BY i.customer_id
```

More info can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html and here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

You could add a second GROUP BY (as many as you want really) if needed. Let's say you want one query that gets "sum by customer, by month". You would do something like...

```
 GROUP BY i.customer_id, DATE_FORMAT(i.due_date, '%Y-%m')
```

The `WITH ROLLUP` can be useful in debugging.

Comment: The other dimension is the date range, group by due_date... Thank you very much for putting me on the right track. I have resolved this now using your method. Thank you again.

Comment: Please read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html